# updating a single row view (ProgressBar) in a listview affects other views

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, view, android-progressbar

I try to show downloading progressBar on a listview. The row.xml contains a relative layout and  I put a framelayout inside the relative layout. I have elements.xml that contains the progressbar. I add the progressbar to the framelayout. Everytime I try to update the single row via getChildAt() other progressBars are also changed.

Thanks.

Comment: can you show us some code

Comment: do not update your stuff with `getChildAt(int)`. Learn about "view recycling"